# Why did Harry not question finding out Snape was a Death Eater?

Tags: harry-potter

In **Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire**, Harry falls into the Pensieve in Dumbledore's office and experiences Dumbledore's memory of Karkaroff's confessions.

During this memory, Karkaroff mentions Snape as a Death Eater, at which point Dumbledore comes to his defence.

Admittedly, I can't remember the books well enough, but **does Harry know about Snape being a Death Eater at this point?** In the films, I'm sure he doesn't.

**If so, why does he not react to this news?**